# WCF Named Pipe Error: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d)

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I have looked at the other posts dealing with "The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d)" but none of them have solved my problem. I have a relatively simple setup bases off of this blog: http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

I feel like I follow it pretty closely, only removing the HTTP binding.

Here is the server code:

```
public class InterProcessServer : IInterProcessServer 
{
    private ServiceHost _host = null;

    public event EventHandler<CommandLineArgsEventArgs> CommandLineArgsReceived;

    protected InterProcessServer(Uri serverAddress, string serviceName)
    {
        IPassCommandLineArgs passArgs = null;
        passArgs = CreatePassCommandLineArgs();
        passArgs.CommandLineArgsReceived += new EventHandler<CommandLineArgsEventArgs> passArgs_CommandLineArgsReceived);

        _host = new ServiceHost(passArgs, new Uri[] { serverAddress });
        _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPassCommandLineArgs), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), serviceName);
        _host.Open();
    }

    public static IInterProcessServer CreateInterProcessServer(Uri serverAddress, string serviceName)
    {
        return new InterProcessServer(serverAddress, serviceName);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            _host.Close();
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void passArgs_CommandLineArgsReceived(object sender, CommandLineArgsEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<CommandLineArgsEventArgs> handler = CommandLineArgsReceived;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(sender, e);
    }

    protected virtual IPassCommandLineArgs CreatePassCommandLineArgs()
    {
        return new PassCommandLineArgs();
    }
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
public class InterProcessClient : IInterProcessClient
{
    private IPassCommandLineArgs _pipeProxy = null;
    private ChannelFactory<IPassCommandLineArgs> _pipeFactory = null;

    protected InterProcessClient(Uri serviceAddress)
    {
        _pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<IPassCommandLineArgs>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress(serviceAddress));
        _pipeProxy = _pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
    }

    public static IInterProcessClient CreateInterProcessClient(Uri serviceAddress)
    {
        return new InterProcessClient(serviceAddress);
    }

    public void SendArgs(string[] args)
    {
        _pipeProxy.PassArgs(args);           
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_pipeFactory != null)
                _pipeFactory.Close();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

I have ensured that the address the client is connecting to is correct. Can anyone provide an idea why I might be getting the error when `_pipeProxy.PassArgs(args);` is called from the client? The test is just between two console apps on the same machine running in different processes.

Framework 4.0 btw.

Thanks!

**EDIT** Here is the service interface and implementation:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPassCommandLineArgs
{
    event EventHandler<CommandLineArgsEventArgs> CommandLineArgsReceived;

    [OperationContract]
    void PassArgs(string[] args);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class PassCommandLineArgs : IPassCommandLineArgs
{
    public event EventHandler<CommandLineArgsEventArgs> CommandLineArgsReceived;

    public void PassArgs(string[] args)
    {
        EventHandler<CommandLineArgsEventArgs> hander = CommandLineArgsReceived;

        if (hander != null)
            hander(this, new CommandLineArgsEventArgs() { Args = args });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Service-Interface IPassCommandLineArgs and all types it uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This was an issue of the calling code passing in an address that had an invalid character to the client. Nothing more.

Comment: You mean the `net.pipe://server:1234/path` address had an invalid character?  What was the character?

Comment: It had a "\0" at the end. Not sure why I didn't see it when I checked the addresses.

Comment: Tcp/ip use ports like :1234.

I don't think that is valid for named pipes.